# What does the app name means above music player in Control Center

Tags: ios, control-center

[image]

Mine is showing "App Store", when clicked, it brings me to App Store, but what is the reason of it showing up in Control center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wording used is to represent the source of the audio content you are listening to, but it tries to be clever and give you more than just the app name.  Instead of Safari, it will scroll the URL of the page you are viewing.  Instead of Music, it will pull the artist/track name etc, and instead of App Store, it will display the name of the last app you were looking at (presumably you were watching a preview video for an app in the store)

Comment: never loads any music to my phone, that is why i never notice it will change according to audio source, thank you

Comment: I have created an app which playing a audio (auto-play from HTML 5 - JS code). Even after killing my app, it's still showing me my app name there? Is it a bug or something that I needs to fix? Or its a usual behavior? FYI, my app ain't a music player app.

Comment: @Hemang That is normal behavior for iOS.